# cpuid + rdtsc and out-of-order execution

Tags: rdtsc

`cpuid` is used as a serializing instruction to prevent ooo execution when benchmarking, since the execution of benchmarked instructions might be reordered before `rdtsc` if it's used alone. My question is whether it is still possible for the instructions below `rdtsc` to be reordered in between `cpuid` and `rdtsc`? Since `rdtsc` is not a serializing instruction, instructions can be freely reordered around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since RDTSC does not depend on any input (it takes no arguments) in principle the OOO pipeline will run it as soon as it can. The reason you add a serializing instruction before it is not to let the RDTSC execute earlier.

There is an answer from John McCalpin [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/280440), you might find it useful. He explains the OOO reordering for the RDTSCP instruction (which behaves differently from RDTSC) which you may prefer to use instead.